# Android Studio main_activity.xml

Tags: android-studio

When I open the main_activity.xml in Android Studio, it doesn't show me the code, it shows me something else shown here:[This is the link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XINCX.png)

How do I change it back to code instead of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the "Text" tab to see the actual XML. You are on "Design" tab which is used for dynamically generating XML on drag and drop of controls.

Comment: Tabs are available for switching under "Component Tree".

Comment: Click on the "Text" tab to switch to see XML. It's visible in the image you shared. In the left half... under "Component Tree" panel... beside "Design" tab...

Comment: Please accept my post as the answer if it worked for you.